# How I can shrink an image (ImageView or ImageButton) without losing pieces of it?

Tags: android, xml, image, imageview, imagebutton

I tell you that I have the following code

```
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:src="@drawable/happy" />
```

[image]

But it is too big and I need to shrink it, but when I do the following happens

[image]

```
                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
                        android:layout_width="44dp"
                        android:layout_height="41dp"
                        android:src="@drawable/happy" />
```

You can see that parts of the image is lost, how can I shrink it without that happens?

Comment: using wieght in layout

Comment: +1 for this question,  a question which is always asked by lot of people, and also a confusing one,however a solvable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you need to resize the original image or you could use an ImageView (which has scaleType param) and make it clickable e.g.

```
<ImageView
     android:id="@+id/smiley_iv"
     android:layout_width="44dp"
     android:layout_height="41dp"
     android:src="@drawable/happy"
     android:scaleType="centerInside" 
     android:clickable="true" />
```

In this case, you'll probably want to add your own background selector (for pressed states etc) and obviously you'll need to add an onClick callback either via xml or programatically.

Comment: @Damian Thanks for your reply, helped me a lot but when I do what you tell me, the image will appear a white background

Comment: actually @pskink is correct, ImageButton extends from ImageView so you can just add android:scaleType="centerInside" to your ImageButton and it'll keep the image ratio. You should accept the answer below.